# How to use python to check for and install library's

Tags: python, pip, package

Is there a way to get this to work as every time I run it, It Won't give me a output, just "PRESS ANY KEY TO CONTINUE..."

as this is currently a test to read the modules I would like it to print the results as well

all help is appreciated

```
# Import the necessary packages
import pip

# Create a list of packages to install
packages_to_install = ["numpy", "pandas", "matplotlib"]

# List all of the installed packages
installed_packages = pip.freeze()

# Compare the list of installed packages to the list of packages to install
for package in packages_to_install:
    if package not in installed_packages:
        # Print the List of uninstalled packages
        print(package)
```

Comment: All your packages  are already installed? [ask] and [mre]

Comment: "It Won't give me a output" - in your own words, what output do you think it should give you, and why? What do you think will happen, if `numpy`, `pandas` and `matplotlib` are all installed already? Did you try, for example, to `print(installed_packages)` before the loop? What result do you get this way?

Comment: As an aside, you should not expect to be able to use the `pip` package to install packages programmatically. Please read https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/user_guide/#using-pip-from-your-program .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
import importlib
import subprocess
import sys

packages_to_install = ["numpy", "pandas", "matplotlib"]

def check_and_install_packages(packages):
    for package in packages:
        try:
            importlib.import_module(package)
            print(f"{package} is already installed.")
        except ImportError:
            print(f"{package} is not installed. Installing...")
            subprocess.check_call([sys.executable, "-m", "pip", "install", package])
            print(f"{package} installed successfully.")

# Check and install packages if needed
check_and_install_packages(packages_to_install)

# Rest of your script can now safely use the installed packages
```

Comment: [Import package](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/glossary/#term-Import-Package) and [distribution package](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/glossary/#term-Distribution-Package) are not the same thing. One should use `importlib.metadata` to check if a distribution package is installed.